# How to enable ssl in dockerized angularjs application deployed in linux container?

Tags: angularjs

I have developed a web application using angular js and deployed in Docker Linux container. I was able to execute/access the application over the network (ex http://172.10.1.1:8082/Login.html). How can I enable SSL in this docker file and redirect to https? 
I am new to Docker deployment and please advise.

Comment: Can u provide the docker file? The process will be very similar to enabling https without docker.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are starting the docker container?

Comment: My docker file as given below

FROM microsoft/aspnet

ARG source

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .


and docker-compose.yml as bellow


version: '2.1'

services:
  sampleapp:
    image: sampleapp
    build:
      context: .\sampleapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile


I will run the container as below

docker run -d -p 8082:80 sampleapp

where sampleapp is image name. This application is created in visual studio 2017 (windows)

Answer (score 0):

My docker file as given below

FROM microsoft/aspnet

ARG source

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .

and docker-compose.yml as bellow

version: '2.1'

services:
  sampleapp:
    image: sampleapp
    build:
      context: .\sampleapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

I will run the container as below

docker run -d -p 8082:80 sampleapp

where sampleapp is image name. This application is created in visual studio 2017 (windows)